# block icmp requests (from fixed network)

Tags: iptables

On my linux box I've 2NICS:

```
br0 192.168.1.0/24 (192.168.1.1 server)
eth1 192.168.2.0/24 lan1
eth2 192.168.3.0/24 lan
[...]
```

there's a routing from eth1 to br0 and also from eth2 to br0

I droppped icmp requests on eth1:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p  icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

but I also want block icmp requests ONLY from 192.168.2.0/24 network on 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the below rule should be your fix:

`iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.1.1 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP`

Anything from source `192.168.2.0/24` with destination `192.168.1.1` with protocol `icmp` with type `echo-request` will be `DROP`'d.

Hope this helps.